# Basic functional equation: $ f ( x y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) $

Tags: functional-equations

> Let $ f $ be any function defined on the set $ \mathbb N $. If $ f ( x y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) $ and $ f ( 2 ) = 9 $, then find $ f ( 3 ) $.

The answer to this question is $ 7 $. Please tell me how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is not true. For instance, $f(x)=9(a_{p_1}+\cdots+a_{p_h})$, where $x=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_h^{a_{p_h}}$ is its prime factorization, satisfies $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(2)=9$. Yet, $f(3)=9$. Specifically, for all functions $g:\{\text{primes}\}\to \Bbb N$, there is exactly one function $f:\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb N$ such that $f(p)=g(p)$ for all primes and $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: Not clear to me.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: No where it is said that f(3)=9..

Comment: I don't (nor can) know why your assignment is wrong, but fact is that a function $f$ such as yours cannot be determined uniquely by the value it takes at $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous, we have $f(x)=\log_a(x)$ for $a$ such that $a^9=2$. So $a>1$ and $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing and we cannot t have $f(3)=7<9=f(2)$.

Comment: It is only defined for positive integer. No question of continuity.